# regex get multiline tag having a word and not another

Tags: regex, pcre

I have to replace all the `<img>` tags containing a text (dog) but not containing another text (cat), for a multiline text

So having this text:

```
<img black 
dog>
<img dog white cat>
<img black dog>
<img cat and dog>
<img red fox>
<img black dog>
```

The following texts should be found:

[image]

There is a lot of ways to find it for single line regex using `^` and `$`, but I am not being able to do it with multiline.

My first attempt was using the single line option (`/s`) this way:

```
/<img ((?!cat).)*?(dog)>/gs
```

But it select the tag before the last dog (red fox) because is not greedy enough.

[image]

And then I made it greedy (adding a `?`) with no `/s` option, using `\s\S`:

```
/<img ((?!cat)[\s\S.])*?(dog)?>/g
```

And I get the fifth tag found again (`<img red fox>`) even when there is no dog.

[image]

How can I get my 3 dogs selected with no cats or foxes?

Link to my attempt in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/AGgb4z/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match `<img`, then assert that there is no `cat` using a negative lookahead `(?![^<>]*cat)`

Use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^<>]*` matching any char except `<` and `>` on the left and the right of dog.

You could use word boundaries for example `\bcat\b` if cat and dog should not be part of a longer word.

```
<img (?![^<>]*cat)[^<>]*dog[^<>]*>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Joy9s/1)

Comment: Why include `<` in the character classes? If the tags are well-formed it shouldn't be possible to encounter a `<` before a `>`.

Comment: @Nick I included those to not allow nested opening `<` and `>`. The OP can omit `<` of course.